# NMSFTP Xcode progress bar

Tags: xcode, progress-bar, sftp

I am working with the NMSFTP Framework for a few weeks now.

I want to add a progress bar to my app when a file is uploading to the server.

How do I get "the progress" from NMSFTP?

Answer (score 0):

```
                       let progressCallback = { (uploadedBytes: UInt) -> Bool in

                            // Update progress
                            let percentOfCurrentFile = Float(uploadedBytes) / Float(totalBytes)

                            return true // do not cancel the upload
                        }

                        // Upload
                        let uploadResult = sftp.writeFileAtPath(localFile.path!, toFileAtPath: "/"+remoteFile,
                                progress: progressCallback)
```